# How to generate CUSTOM HTML Report in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, testing, scala-collections, scala-2.10, scalatest

I am able to generate HTML Report for my scala test file via following task in my build.sbt:

```
lazy val scalaTestRun = inputKey[Unit]("custom run task for test")
scalaTestRun := {
    val one = (runMain in Compile).fullInput(" org.scalatest.tools.Runner -s          com.pg.macro.testcase.AutoTest -h ScalaTestReport").evaluated
}
```

This generates me a report like following:

[image]

Is there any way I can customise this report's content. Say I want to change the header name "SalaTest Results" to something related with my test suite name.

I saw the HTMLReporter class (org.scalatest.tools.HtmlReporter) in scalatest jar where they have hard coded this header value it seems.

Comment: I realize this was asked 3 years ago..did you ever get any response for doing this?